# HTTP Body in NSURLRequest

Tags: string, swift, utf-8, nsdata

I want to build 2 functions to construct the HTTPBody to pass to `NSURLRequest`.

**Function 1:** Accepts `NSDictionary`, which needs to converted into `NSData`

**Function 2:** Accepts `NSString`,  which needs to converted into `NSData`

**Code For Function 1:**

```
//HTTPBodyParameters is of the type NSDictionary which is the input parameter

    let HTTPBody : NSData?

    do {
        HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(HTTPBodyParameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {

        print("Error in creating body - \(error)")

        HTTPBody = nil
    }
```

**Questions:**

1. Does my code hold good for all scenarios when the input is an NSDictionary or is there a better approach ?
2. How to convert String (swift) into NSData without using NSString ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer for point 1:

```
   //You can type cast to AnyObject. So it can accept to NSDictionary and NSString
   request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(str as AnyObject, options: nil, error: &error)
```

This is the answer for point 2:

```
 var str: String = "teststring"
 var data: NSData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: In most of the examples online, I have seen that the NSJSONSerialization is used everywhere. Important part is that it should fulfil your requirement and give the desired output you need.